# Get data from User Model - Showing Error -> Property [name] does not exist on this collection instance

Tags: laravel

I use this code bellow on controller

```
public function ClassName($ids)
{
    
    $data['tittle'] = 'User Dashboard';        
    $data['users'] = User::FindOrFail(Auth::user()->id);
    
    return view('user.pagname', $data);
}
```

and write the code `{{$users->name}}` on the layout page, it's not working on "user.pagname.blade.php file but on index blade file it's working, please help me what is the wrong here

showing this error "Property [name] does not exist on this collection instance."

Comment: Can you please add the controller function where `view('index')` is called?

Comment: yes this is working on index, but not working on other view

Comment: `findOrFail()` doesn't return an instance of `Collection`. It's either `Model` or `null`

Comment: You cannot access it like that. You must do: `{{ $data['users']->name }}`

Comment: its working "{{ $data['users']->name }}"

Comment: @MsuRubel ok mark the answer below as correct so other can see it too please

Answer (score 0):

You cannot access it like that. The variable $data is an array so you must do:

`{{ $data['users']->name }}`